# Single Query in Medium RC Causing CPU to 100% in Azure Dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: azure-synapse

we have had a single user in our dedicated SQL pool spike the CPU to 100% on her own previously. We believe this is due to her query having multiple subqueries and being in a medium resource class. However, we cannot tell the execution plan. We typically operate at 500 DWU, which has 20 concurrency slots with the medium rc getting two slots.

If the query has, what looks like 4 or 5 subqueries, should we expect that this query to take a total of 10 concurrency slots? Also, how do we look at the execution plan? It doesn't seem the same as normal SQL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very hard to tell as to if the sub queries are the real culprits . To me I think the data plays a bigger role . For the execution plan , not sure if you have gone through this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor) , it should help .

Comment: So, your thought is that the data movement/shuffling is causing the major spike in the CPU? Yes, we have used this article previously, but each time we have to scale up before our analysis is done to not impact the business. I will concede that the table in question has well over a billion rows. We plan to re-run the query after hours to do the query analysis at that time to see what activity might be causing the issue.

Comment: I will update this thread once we have the results. Thank you!

Comment: We did run the testing that weekend. The sample query ran within 60 seconds. In addition, we ran 5 additional concurrent ones. We did see that 60% of the compute was taken with each of the queries in a Medium RC. What we didn't realize is that we may not have been seeing all of the running queries in query activity. Is there a delay on that? I suspect the only guaranteed way to see all of the queries is through this DMV? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor#step-1-identify-the-query-you-wish-to-investigate

Comment: The CPU is spiking because of a massive data shuffle. We did end up opening a ticket with the Microsoft team for Dedicated SQL Pool. We are trying to decide with the data analyst end-user if it makes sense to go through some query efficiency analysis. Thanks!